# Numpy, pandas and requests modules not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have anaconda packages installed but neither numpy, nor requests are available as a module in jupyter notebook, I am very new in technology, basically a medical school graduate trying to learn Python. Please help! I had already tried to uninstall and re install it, but didn't help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: which operating system are you working on?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm on windows 10!

Comment: Can you paste the code you are trying? Have you imported those packages first?

Comment: yess i have imported packags 1st and then launched jupyter to work on PubMed database... im trying to get a list of 20 publications with keyword fever, and also want to calculate statistics on an another database ... both modules are displaying as they are not available...

Comment: for example modules like numbers, math etc. are working

Comment: Since I don't know if pandas is installed in your anaconda environment. You can use `!pip install pandas` in one the cell in your notebook and try importing pandas again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on Linux, so all my suggestions would not be relevant.. Good luck